# Rounding errors when scaling the rendered output of the rich edit control via EM_FORMATRANGE

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, richtextbox

I am using the [`EM_FORMATRANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to render the output of a rich text control to an arbitrary device context.  However, when rendering to a bitmap, the dots-per-inch of the bitmap's device context is the same as the display device's DPI, which is 96 dots-per-inch.  This is much lower than what I would like to render to.  I'd rather render at a much higher DPI so that the user can zoom in, and perhaps print on a high-DPI printer later.

I suspect what happens is that the RTF control calls [`GetDeviceCaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY` to get the number of pixels per inch of the device.  It then renders the document using this DPI value at a 100% zoom level.  Windows display devices always return a value of 96 DPI, unless large fonts are being used on the system (as set in Control Panel) and the application is DPI-aware.

Many examples on the Internet propose scaling the output of `EM_FORMATRANGE`.  This is so that any arbitrary DPI resolution can be achieved.  Most examples generally involve using [`SetMapMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`SetWindowExtEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [`SetViewportExtEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (e.g. see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/netfxbcl/thread/37fd1bfb-f07b-421d-9b5e-5f4492ffbbc3).  These functions can be used to scale the rich text control's rendered output:  for example, if I specify 400% scaling, then if the rich text control rendered something that was 5 pixels wide, it would actually become 20 pixels wide.

Unfortunately, the old GDI functions use integers instead of floating point numbers.  For example, suppose the RTF control decided that an element should be drawn at (12.7, 15.3) pixels.  This would be rounded to a position of (13, 15).  These rounded coordinates are passed to GDI, which then scales up the image using scaling specified by `SetMapMode`: for the example of 400%, it would be (13*4, 15*4), or (52, 60).  But this is not accurate: the element would have better been placed at (12.7*4, 15.3*4), or (51, 61).  The worst part is that for some cases, the error becomes cumulative.

I believe this is the underlying cause of this very noticeable error when scaling some simple text:

[image: Rendered using EM_FORMATRANGE<code>and scaled with</code>SetMapMode]

The above example is 8 point Segoe UI, scaled to 400% using `EM_FORMATRANGE` and `SetMapMode` on a 96 DPI display device context.  The text has now become 32 point size, but the space between each character is too high and looks unnatural.

[image: Zoomed to 400% in WordPad]

The above example was created in WordPad by entering the text as 8 point Segoe UI and then using the zoom control to set to a 400% zoom level.  The space between each character looks normal.  The exact same result is achieved with a 32 point font and 100% zoom level.

To work around this issue, I have tried the following.  For each thing tried, the result has been identically unsatisfactory when scaled to 400%.

- Using a scaling transform set using [`SetWorldTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of the scaling done with `SetMapMode` and `SetWindowExtEx` etc.
- Passing the device context for a metafile to `EM_FORMATRANGE`, and then scaling the metafile later.
- Using `SetMapMode` to scale in conjunction with rendering to a metafile, and then showing the metafile later without scaling.

I believe the results are always unsatisfactory because the problem boils down to the fact that the rich edit control is rounding to the nearest integer and rendering to what it thinks is a 96 DPI device - ignoring the transforms in place.  I looked into the metafile format and what I discovered is that the individual character positions are actually stored in the metafile at pixel-level resolution - that's why scaling the metafile obviously didn't work since the rounding has already happened by that point.

I can think of two real solutions that would work around this issue:

- Use a device context with a higher user-specified dots per inch, such that `GetDeviceCaps` returns different values.  (Note: some examples propose using the printer device since they generally have higher DPI, but I want my code to work on systems that don't have a printer and be able to render to an off-screen buffer).
- Some way to tell the rich edit control to assume the device context has a different dots per inch than reported by `GetDeviceCaps`.

Anything else seems like it would still be subject to these rounding errors.

Does anyone (1) have an idea of how to implement either of the solutions I have proposed, or (2) have an alternate idea of how to achieve my goal of getting an accurate high-DPI output into a buffer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem.

A quick solution is to draw the text into 100% scale bitmap, and then just scale the bitmap.
it's not the best solution, but it might work for you.

Did you find any better solutions? if so, please share them here.

Also notice, that this problem also occurs when you draw the text to a 100% meta-file and then scale the meta-file to the screen - I believe this has something to do with GDI text drawing functions that aren't working well with scaling.

Roey

Comment: Bitmap scaling is just trading one evil for another.  The resulting image would be blurry: why bother outputting to the high DPI image in the first place?  The metafile approach didn't work for me either - I think due to the same rounding error problems - the results were identically erroneous.

Comment: I only thought of two possible solutions:  (1) create a windowless rich edit control, zoom it, and ask it to render to an arbitrary device context that's not actually a window.  This might be the best way because it uses a supported interface.  (2) hook the GetDeviceCaps function and make it lie about about LOGPIXELSX and LOGPIXELSY for your specific device context, to trick the rich edit control into rendering at the desired DPI.  But this would be unsupported/undocumented, obviously.  I have not had time to investigate either solution. If you get a solution working I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: solution (1): from my experience, trying to draw gdi (not gdi+) text into a surface which is not a screen surface will give you bad results because font smoothing will not work (i've struggled this issue for days).
solution (2): i have no idea how to do so :) do you have xp in that field?

Comment: #1: If it's not a screen surface then you are using a printer surface; why would you want ClearType font smoothing on the printer?  ClearType is designed for LCDs.  (Actually, if I could turn off font smoothing when rendering rich text to a screen surface, it would be quite helpful because I want to save that surface to a file for later printing.)

Comment: #2:  A little, although I wouldn't recommend it if there is any way at all to do it without hooking.  If the windowless rich edit method or another method can do the job, then it would be the preferred solution.  Hooking crosses the line from depending on published interfaces to depending on implementation details.  Jeffrey Richter's Windows via C/C++ book has a chapter on API hooking, along with sample code.  Also see Microsoft Detours, and several other open source API hooking libraries.

Comment: not an answer, but provides more info: http://books.google.co.il/books?id=-O92IIF1Bj4C&pg=PA1119&lpg=PA1119&dq=gdi+-%22gdi%2B%22+text+scale+problem&source=bl&ots=SxZKK37jqc&sig=rM2quCs7wKWk9eqJwYmbdF4-9HU&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=gdi%20-%22gdi%2B%22%20text%20scale%20problem&f=false

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the point size of all the text in the control by a factor of 4 and render the control to a bitmap that's 4 times larger.

If you're populating the control yourself this would be quite straightforward.  If you support arbitrary content entered by the user it would be a lot more work and would require extra effort to handle anything that wasn't text (e.g. embedded bitmaps).

Answer (score 0):

I just spent two weeks on a similar problem.  I needed a Rich Edit that was scalable for WYSISWG editing.  As we've found the windows rich edit control does not support scaling correctly with EM_FORMATRANGE and inter character spacing does not change between zoom levels and font sizes only scale in discrete font size steps.

Since I did not need large differences in scale the solution I settled on was to use the windowless text edit interfaces from ITextServices to render to an internal bitmap at a fixed resolution.  Then I used GDI+ to resample the internal bitmap to the needed screen size with trilinear filtering.  The results emulated a scalable rich edit well enough as long as scale difference were not too large, it was good enough for my needs.

After trying many different options I am convinced you can not get precise scaling with the windows rich edit control.  You can write your own control that renders text.  However, you would need to have a separate draw call for every piece of text with a different style.  Also you would need to handle all the nicities rich edit handles for you like highlighting text, placing the cursor, handling mouse and keyboard input, parsing rtf text, et cetera.  It would probably be best just to buy a third party component in this case(I could not find any suitable free open source components).  In case someone wants to attempt it I will point out the relevant starting points for text rendering for different APIs.

- GDI - TextOut does not set inter-character spacing correctly.  You need GetCharacterPlacement and ExTextOut.  You also need to calculate scaling yourself.  You probably don't want to use GDI
- GDI+ - DrawString handles scaling correctly.  GDI+ is a reasonable option
- DirectWrite - If you are willing to limit yourself to Vista Platform Update or later, DirectWrite is the newest text API from Microsoft.

Also here is link describing how text rendering is different between GDI and GDI+:

http://windowsclient.net/articles/gdiptext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`EM_SETZOOM` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to let the rich edit control scale the output itself.

Comment: I'm familiar with that message.  It doesn't affect the output of EM_FORMATRANGE.  How then do you propose to redirect this zoomed output to somewhere else other than an interactive window? (which was what EM_SETZOOM is intended for)

Comment: @JamesJohnston, having never tried it and since you didn't mention it either, I assumed it would affect all rendering. My bad.